# Why does Facebook Pixel Parameter "currency" shows invalid?

Tags: facebook-pixel

I was implementing a pixel event on my website and I had to provide a currency for my local business. It was Bangladeshi currency (BDT). But the following error is shown:

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
  value: 350,
  currency: 'BDT'
});
```

Now it shows the following error.

> Facebook Pixel Error: Parameter "currency" is invalid for event "Purchase"

Can anyone tell me if Facebook supports Bangladeshi currency?

Comment: Facing the same problem though facebook marketing api supports BDT currency.

Comment: Because you need to add 2 decimal

Answer (score 1):

**Yes BDT currency is supported. you just need to add this**

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=FB_PIXEL_ID&ev=Purchase&cd[currency]=BDT&cd[value]=350"/>
```

here is supported currency list:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/currencies/